# How to get crash logs on IOS SDK Development using Sentry

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sentry

I develop an `IOS SDK`, which developers can implement it to their apps as a `framework`.

I’m currently using `Sentry` as crash analysis tool, and the related `DSYM` file (produced from my SDK project) is automatically uploaded to `Sentry` on every build.

But the problem is when someone’s app crashes due to an error on the SDK I’m developing, Sentry returns partially symbolicated crash logs that I can barely understand what has happened and where the crash has occurred.

Is there a way that I can get the fully symbolicated crash logs, without changing the app’s project settings and without uploading anything (app’s `DSYM` etc.) from the original app. (Since I don’t have the app, I’m only producing the SDK)

My project has the following build settings:

- Strip Debug Symbols During Copy: No
- Strip Style: Debugging Symbols
- Strip Linked Product: No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was sending the DSYM's to a wrong project. I set 'export SENTRY_PROJECT=proper_project_name' then the issue has resolved. 
Here is the link of the issue;
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cocoa/issues/277

Comment: Consider marking this is solved to help others that may have the same issue